# Change background and foreground color of special windows

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, themes, colors

I'm customizing my Xubuntu theme. With [GNOME Color Chooser](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-color-chooser/) I can change most of the default option regarding the colours of windows background. But seems that for some special widows like Volume Control, Ubuntu Software Center I don't have any possibility to control the background and the foreground colour. Unfortunately, I don't know why, they have a very bad colour combination (white foreground in a light grey background see figure) so I don't see anything.

[image]

**How can I change the background color of these "special windows"?** Even a default scheme for these one for me goes well but not white over light gray!

Comment: Which theme is this? Have you tried the default Greybird theme?

Comment: @DKBose is albatross! Yes in fact if a change the theme I solve the problem but I don't like very much with Greybird, I would like to use albatross and change only these windows...